# Kivy adding multible labels when only one label is given

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to make a minesweeper game in kivy and I ran into some trouble with the kv language. Specificity it adds two labels into the main window I only tell it to add one. This is very strange because when I run all the code by itself in a different document it works perfectly. Although I have found a way around this problem, overriding my widgets `__init__` I would like to use the kivy code instead since it would be much easier. Here is the relevant code and the result of it:

The kv-file:

```
<ScoreBoard>:
    cols: 3
    size_hint: (1, 0.2)

    Label:
        id: mines
        text: 'mines'
```

And the python-file:

```
class ScoreBoard(GridLayout):
    """
    This is the field at the top of the screen, displaying how many mines
    are left, current time and the smiley reset button.

    More code in .kv file
    """
    def add_widget(self, widget):
        super().add_widget(widget)
        print('Score board add widget ', widget)
```

I added my own `add_widget` method to see whether or not it was called twice and I found that it was called twice. This is the resulting screen of the code above:

[image: The screen of the code]

I guess that the part that adds the `ScoreBoard` object is also relevant since I can't replicate the result if I move the kivy code and python code to a separate file so here it is:

```
class Menu(AnchorLayout):

    def new_window(self, next_win):
        """
        Change the window to next_win.
        """
        parent = self.parent 
        parent.remove_widget(self)
        parent.add_widget(next_win)
```

The above code is run when the user presses a button and then the ScoreBoard is added to the screen.

I am using Python 3.4 and Kivy 1.9

If any more code is necessary then I can post the code here or give a link to my bitbucket repository.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't adding the label a second time with the line super().add_widget(widget)? I know you say you added this, to solve that same problem, but it looks like it could cause it.

Comment: @Totem no I know that that is not causing the problem since for the most parts I didn't have that there, I only added that recently to debug the code.

Comment: If I were you, I would start stripping back the code in search of the culprit. For instance, I'd start commenting out various methods/functions piece by piece, while still allowing the basic GUI to be run each time. You'll likely find that suddenly the problem disappears, and then you'll know the origin. I imagine that the code isn't too long altogether, so it shouldn't take too long.